# iOS iterate UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, iteration

I have a UITableView that collects data from a database. What I would like to know is if there is some way I can iterate in the UITableView collection and check the values of the cell? The reason I ask is because I would like to update each cell based on the current value that it has (change font, size, color, etc.). I've seen in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115639/iterate-in-a-uitableview-iphone) SO post regarding this topic, but since the cells are already created and their values are changed it is a bit harder for me. I was thinking of iterating through the UITableView before I call `reloadData`, but any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not iterate over the cells of `UITableView`, because some of them (in fact, most of them) may not be present until you request them. `UITableView` aggressively recycles its cells, so if a cell is not visible, it is very likely that you would be creating it from scratch only to put it back into recycle queue moments later.

Changing your model and calling `reloadData` the way your post suggests would be the right solution. iOS will ensure that it runs the update in a smallest number of CPU cycles possible, so you do not need to worry about the cells that are already created. This is also the easiest approach in terms of your coding effort.

Comment: How would I be able to check the data inside the cells to perform the proper format changes in them though? Since I am assigning the UITable to pull data from the database I do not have full control over the values I am receiving until after I have received them and displayed them in the cell. What I am trying to do is make a small inventory system that pulls from the database and depending on the type of item format the cells. I would like to make the first column font bold, make each item's drop type their respectful color, and set the item name's background color relevant to its type.

Comment: The right place to do this would be in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation. This is where `UITableView` expects you to populate a cell with data and configure its appearance.

Comment: @Seb You can implement all this in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. When you create a `UITableViewCell` to return from the method, or set up a recycled one for reuse, you set the content to whatever is the value that you got from your database. This is the right place to also examine the value, and set the styling elements of your `UITableViewCell` as you need before returning it to the `UITableView` to display.

Comment: Thank you all for clarifying this information for me. Greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

A table view is for displaying data. The properties of your table cells should only be written to, not read from. The appropriate way of handling this situation would be to update your underlying model objects -- the objects that you use to populate the table view -- as the data changes, and then reload the affected rows.

The issue you'll encounter is that `UITableView` reuses table cells. Once a table cell scrolls off the screen, it's quite likely that the table view will reuse the same cell to display a different row.

This means it's fundamentally not possible to iterate over the table cells. When you need to refresh a row because its data has changed, you should call [`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW40) (or `reloadData` if all rows have changed) and if the row is visible on screen, `UITableView` will call your data source methods and give you an opportunity to configure the cell for display.